# PHP cookies not working in IE

Tags: php, internet-explorer, cookies, setcookie

I am creating a cookies using PHP, below is an example of one of the cookies:

`setcookie("LogPasswordError", "Please enter your Password.", time()+1, '/');`

It is created in the file `loginForm.php` if the users password is incorrect this cookie if it is set is then echo'd out in the `HTML` form which is in a different file. In IE the cookie is not being set however it works in Firefox and Chrome. Why is the cookie not being set in IE?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE?

Try this if you are on localhost:

setcookie("LogPasswordError", "Please enter your Password.", time()+3600, '/', **false**);

this means use current time plus 3600,and the **false** means not use https protocol.

Comment: IE 10, does it make a difference if it is on localhost? (which I am) The cookie seems to now be created however after the header redirects back to the index page the cookie doesn't show until I refresh the page myself.